# Codingbat challenge: mirrorEnds using Stream API

Tags: java, string, java-stream

Given the task [mirrorEnds](https://codingbat.com/prob/p139411) from *CodingBat*:

> Given a string, look for a mirror image (*backwards*) string at both
> the beginning and end of the given string.
>
> In other words, zero or
> more characters at the very beginning of the given string, and at the
> very end of the string in reverse order (*possibly overlapping*). For
> example, the string `"abXYZba"` has the mirror end `"ab"`.

*Examples:*

```
mirrorEnds("abXYZba")  →  "ab"
mirrorEnds("abca")     →  "a"
mirrorEnds("aba")      →  "aba"
```

My solution for this task is the following:

```
public String mirrorEnds(String str) {
  String result = "";
  
  if (str.length() % 2 != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1)) {
        result += "" + str.charAt(i);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (result.length() == str.length() / 2) {
      String strEnd = new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString();
      result += "" + str.charAt(str.length() / 2) + strEnd;
    } 
  }
  
  if (str.length() % 2 == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1)) {
        result += "" + str.charAt(i);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (result.length() == str.length() / 2) {
      String strEnd = new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString();
      result += strEnd;
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem using ***Stream API*** ?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're **purposely asking for a stream-solution** to this problem, this could be to look for the greatest index `i` where the first `i` characters match the last `i` characters reversed, with `i` starting from `length() / 2` and proceeding by decrementing `i` until it reaches 0.

The previous algorithm makes sense to be applied only if the given string isn't a palindrome. In fact, in that case, the string itself could be returned immediately.

```
public static String mirrorEnds(String str) {
    if (str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString())) {
        return str;
    }

    OptionalInt maxLen = IntStream.iterate(str.length() / 2, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
            .filter(i -> str.substring(0, i).equals((new StringBuilder(str.substring(str.length() - i))).reverse().toString()))
            .max();

    return maxLen.isPresent() ? str.substring(0, maxLen.getAsInt()) : null;
}
```

##### Output

```
ab
a
aba
```

Here is a link to test the code:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rUL

Answer (score 2):

I think Stream API wouldn't give you any advantage. however, you can optimize your code like this

```
  public String mirrorEnds(String string) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(string.length() - i - 1)) {
            result.append(string.charAt(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: You can optimize it even further: `for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { if(string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(string.length() - i - 1)) return string.substring(0, i); } return string;`

Answer (score 2):

It's doable with `IntStream.range()` in a *single stream-statement*.

In order to create a one-liner we will need'll a help of `takeWhile()`, which was introduced with Java 9. `takeWhile()` is a so-called *short-cercuit* operation, i.e. it will break after the first element that doesn't match the given *predicate*.

```
public static String mirrorEnds(String str) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
        .takeWhile(i -> str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i))
        .map(str::codePointAt)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Since *CodingBat* is still on Java 8, its compiler will complain at the code above.

---

A very nice, a simple Java 8 compliant solution proposed by *@Holger*.

It looks for the index of the *first mismatch* between characters at the beginning and at the end, and generates a substring starting from the very beginning `0` up to the`mismatch` index.

In case if `findFirst()` returns an empty optional, i.e. the given string is a *palindrome* and there's no mismatch, the length of the given string will be provided via `orElse()`.

The code below passes all tests on *CodingBat*.

```
public String mirrorEnds(String str) {
        
        int mismatch = IntStream.range(0, str.length() / 2)
            .filter(i -> str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(str.length());
        
        return str.substring(0, mismatch);
    }
```

*Note* since *CodingBat* disallows *imports*, in order to run the code above on this site you need to use a so-called fully-qualified name of the class `java.util.stream.IntStream`.

Comment: Shorter and Java 8 compatible: `return str.substring(0, IntStream.range(0, str.length())
          .filter(i -> str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i))
          .findFirst().orElse(str.length()));`

Comment: @Holger A really nice and performant solution. It can be enhanced by replacing `range(0, str.length())` with `range(0, str.length() / 2)` because there's no need to iterate past the middle of the given string, it's already proven to be a palindrome - we can return the whole length. Incorporated this solution into the answer.